# python: Is there a way to get the code inside the with statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I was hoping this would work:

```
class A:
    def __enter__(self, code):
       print code

    def __exit__(..):
       pass
```

and then:

```
with A():
   f()
   g()
```

would print:

```
f()
g()
```

Specifically, my intention is to take this code and create a function out of it. So I can do: `with runInThreads()` or `with runManyTimesTillSuccess()`,..

Comment: What's wrong with passing a function to another function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could use a decorator with an argument:

```
>>> def manytimes(n):
    def decorate(fn):
        for i in range(n):
            fn()
    return decorate

>>> @manytimes(3)
def _():
    print("hello")


hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: I hate admitting I was wrong but the "withhacks" is just too hacky.. I like the "with" solution much better than the "decorator" solution because it's much more elegant. I hope python adds it to the language some day..

Answer (score 6):

In a portable, language defined way, no. However, the [withhacks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/withhacks) module provides several examples of CPython specific hackery that lets you do all sorts of creative things.

That's more for playing around, though - functions and generators are still the only official ways of playing with reusable code blocks in Python.

Comment: Well +1.  I have gained knowledge.  Now bleakly, comes Chapel Perilous.  I have gained knowledge.  Have I gained wisdom? This is a great evil, I say that by how seductive it is.  @carl is right.  This is so wrong.  Going to walk under the stars, away from the terminal.  So very cool though.

Comment: I saw Ryan give a lightning talk on this at Pycon AU last year. Definitely evil, evil, stuff. Fun, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a decorator?

I just tried (I still have python 2.6.4 here, but it will surely work with newer ones too)

```
def decorate(fn):
    print "Got", fn
    return "Anything"

def foo():
    @decorate
    def bar(): pass
    print bar

foo()
foo()
```

and it gives:

```
Got <function bar at 0x01EAD4B0>
Anything
Got <function bar at 0x01EAD4B0>
Anything
```

so you can easily do:

```
any code...
@runInThreads
def _():
    whatever...
```

You can even define `_` any number of times in a function.

PS: I read the [link](http://billmill.org/multi_line_lambdas.html) from [withhacks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/withhacks), than thought this up and wanted to comment there too only to notice the same technique is already suggested in the [comments there](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9cnaw/multiline_lambdas_in_python_using_the_with/).

Answer (score 0):

Using ncoghlan's advice I went to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/withhacks and got the code off:
http://code.google.com/p/ouspg/wiki/AnonymousBlocksInPython?ts=1253546882&updated=AnonymousBlocksInPython

so I can do:

```
from blocks import takes_block

@takes_block
def manyTimes(block):
   for i in range(5):
      block()


 with manyTimes():
     print 'a'
     print 'b'
```

which printouts: `a b` 5 times.

Comment: Yuck. It gives you nothing you couldn't already do cleanly with a decorator.

Comment: I can pass parameters to `manyTimes` for example: `with manyTime(numOfTimes=2, ..)`. Is this possible with a decorator?

Comment: Yes of course. Decorators are just functions, so they can take arguments. I'll need to show you that as an answer though as comments aren't up to it.